# Building Raspberry Pi GTK app in a docker enviroment

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, gtk3, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to build a C GTK app on my windows desktop that will run on a raspberry pi.

I'm using a docker container running ubuntu.

I have installed

- eclipse
- gtk3.0

I have included the library and can build a GTK app that just opens a window with nothing in it as a test and it runs with no errors.

I tried to move this on to the Pi an it returned an exec format error.

After a short google I realised it's because I used the standard gcc and not a 32 bit one.

I installed arm-linux-gcueabihf and configured the compiler.

Now when I try to compile I get the error.

```
usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideaa on where to go from here or can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

I've gone down the container route so I could save the container as an image when I have it all set up.
So I can create new containers in the future without all this hassle.